# Djano format TextField space every 4 digits (IBAN)

Tags: django, format, textfield

I'm having a TextField and in my form and I'm trying to make a space every 4 digits because I want the IBAN format of 16 digits XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX.

I read about the python package "django-iban" and imported it, but the form formatting didnt work.

Is there another way to force the TextField to make a space every 4 digits?

Comment: This sounds like frontend issue. Check onkeyup event:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp

Answer (score 0):

**[django-iban](https://pypi.org/project/django-iban/)** is an  Obsolete package You should not use this package any longer . the IBAN   fields is  available in [django-localflavor](https://django-localflavor) . this package  used to live in Django , but it is separated into a standalone package you can  check the full list of [fields](https://django-localflavor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) .
this is an example how to use **iban field**   :

```
from localflavor.generic.forms import  IBANFormField

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    iban = IBANFormField()
```

Comment: I exactly had this code in my project. I assumed that the formatting isnt included in this IbanField because the formatting in my Form wasnt showing.

Comment: I used your code and all the codes from the localflavor docs but still get this:

https://dvx.so/img/8DF4